# Parsing pl/sql with regular expressions, need to strip out the literals

Tags: java, regex

Say I have a body of code with strings:

```
declare
   string varchar(255);
begin
   string := ''' this is a string ^''^ is the delimiter';
   dbms_output.put_line(string);
end;
```

delimited by '
escaped by ''

I need to return the same code and

- get a list of the strings in order of occurence
- get the code back with the strings omitted

I would expect to find the string:

```
' this is a string ^'^ is the delimiter
```

and the stripped code would be

```
declare
   string varchar(255);
begin
   string := ;
   dbms_output.put_line(string);
end;
```

it would be truly awesome if the stripped code had placemarkers

```
declare
   string varchar(255);
begin
   string := %{1}s;
   dbms_output.put_line(string);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this pattern might work for you:

`'(''|[^'])*'`

It works by finding a first `'` then any subsequent `''` or anything that's not a lone `'` is ignored until the final lone `'` is found.

It is able to find these full strings:

```
'this is a string'
''
''' this is a string ^''^ is the delimiter'
'complex string ''quoted'' continued string ''quote again'''
```

etc etc.

Try it out and see if it works for you.
Please test it on complex cases with lots of `'` to make sure it's valid.

Here it is in action:

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(''|[^'])*'");
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = 
              "declare\r\n"
            + "   string varchar(255);\r\n"
            + "begin\r\n"
            + "   string := ''' this is a string ^''^ is the delimiter';\r\n"
            + "   dbms_output.put_line(string);\r\n"
            + "end;";

    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(input.length());
    int count = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "%{" + (++count) + "}s");
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.   I have written a lot of regular expressions but this one made my head hurt.  I usually text with https://regex101.com/

Comment: Yea, that's a great site for testing out regex. Glad I could help.